# identifier "aa_bb" is not in camel case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmlct.jpg)

I try to add the rule in the .eslintrc, But it does not work.

Please help.

I get 'aa_bb' from the api. I add the rule like the doc, and some ways.

It is still doesn't work. My classmate tell me to delete the eslint, he

think that is superfluous.

oh, i can't add more detail......

```js
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": ["compat"],
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "jest": true,
        "jasmine": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "generator-star-spacing": [0],
        "consistent-return": [0],
        "react/forbid-prop-types": [0],
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js"] }],
        "global-require": [1],
        "import/prefer-default-export": [0],
        "react/jsx-no-bind": [0],
        "react/prop-types": [0],
        "react/prefer-stateless-function": [0],
        "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": ["error", {
            "declaration": "parens-new-line",
            "assignment": "parens-new-line",
            "return": "parens-new-line",
            "arrow": "parens-new-line",
            "condition": "parens-new-line",
            "logical": "parens-new-line",
            "prop": "ignore"
        }],
        "no-else-return": [0],
        "no-script-url": 0,
        "no-restricted-syntax": [0],
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [0],
        "no-use-before-define": [0],
        "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": [0],
        "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": [0],
        "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": [0],
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [0],
        "no-nested-ternary": [0],
        "arrow-body-style": [0],
        "import/extensions": [0],
        "no-bitwise": [0],
        "no-cond-assign": [0],
        "import/no-unresolved": [0],
        "camelcase": [
          "error", {
            "properties": "never"
          }
        ],
        "comma-dangle": ["error", {
            "arrays": "always-multiline",
            "objects": "always-multiline",
            "imports": "always-multiline",
            "exports": "always-multiline",
            "functions": "ignore"
        }],
        "object-curly-newline": [0],
        "function-paren-newline": [0],
        "no-restricted-globals": [0],
        "require-yield": [1],
        "compat/compat": "error",
      // "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"]
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "polyfills": ["fetch", "promises"]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just disable inline wherever you are using ? `// eslint-disable-line`

Answer (score 5):

Is that your entire `.eslintrc` file, or just a snippet? If the former, it looks like `.eslintrc` files need to start and end with curly braces. So try:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": ["error", {"properties": "never"}]
    }
}
```

If it's just a snippet, what version of ESLint are you using? I think in some of the earlier 1.x versions, instead of "error", you used a number representing the level:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": [2, {"properties": "never"}]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a snippet. I find some ways in the internet，(include your answer)，but it is still doesn't work。。I updated the question now。

Comment: The first snippet worked for me when added to eslintrc file. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

camelCase is a naming convention in which each word within a compound word is capitalized except for the first word. Software developers often use camelCase when writing source code.

camelCase is useful in programming since element names cannot contain spaces. The camelCase naming convention makes compound names more readable. For example, myOneMethod is easier to read than myonemethod.

```
add_bb for addFor
```

Answer (score 3):

This moved forward, you can now flexibly `allow` certain identifiers (regexp also) to be non-camelcase:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": ["error", {"allow": ["aa_bb"]}]
    }
}
```

See: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase#allow

Answer (score 0):

In the event that modifying your `eslint` config is not an option, you can simply destructure and then rename that property.

```
const { first_name: firstName } = data;
```